# How to add Definiton of Symfony Dependency injection container builder from Class factory method?

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

For example:  I have one class which have `ClassA::create()`;

How to register this factory in `ContainerBuilder`?

```
$containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();

$containerBuilder
    ->register('access_manager', AccessManager::class)
    ->addArgument([new Reference('post_voter')]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You call `setFactory()`.

E.g.:

```
$containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();

$containerBuilder
    ->register('access_manager', AccessManager::class)
    ->addArgument([new Reference('post_voter')]);

$containerBuilder->register(ClassA::class)
                  ->setClass(ClassA::class)
                  ->setFactory([ClassA::class, 'create']);
```

If you want the factory to create new instances of the service each time it's accessed, you'd need to add a call to `setShared(false)`.

Here you can see an example on an online sandbox:
https://phpsandbox.io/e/x/qhhxv

(Click on "run" on the bottom right to see it working).